# Soft Question - Book Recommendations (Diff Geo, Bose-Einstein stats etc.)

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, statistical-mechanics

I apologise immediately for the soft question but I will still ask it. I feel there may be a lot of people in the same boat so it may be relevant to a large number of others.

With context of this coronavirus stuff going on, it's the perfect time to get some extra reading done. I'm currently a second-year maths student, with exams in the next few weeks, and am looking for some recommendations on some 'mathematical physics' type books for after. I'm pretty far through Wald's GR (some of the questions are a pain but that's another story), and am wondering if anyone could suggest some books on, for example, Differential Geometry or Bose-Einstein Statistics (personally I have a book on QM that I'm getting through, albeit slower than GR due to interest reasons, however it may be helpful for others if you have a suggestion for that area too). I would love to have some recommendations on generally anything that you may have wished you'd read about during your undergrad, or even just a fantastic book on an area of mathematics in general.

Again, apologies for the soft question.

Comment: I've read a bit of G. Naber's Geometry of Minkowski Space. Really broaden my horizon about mathematical relativity.

Comment: For geometric (and in general mathematical) aspects of physics I warmly suggest you to enjoy Frederic Schuller's lectures on YouTube. They are excellently taught.

Answer (score 0):

Based on where you're at and what you're interested in, I think an uncontroversial choice would be Nakahara's "Geometry, Topology, and Physics." I like what I've read of "Mathematics for Physics" by Stone and Goldbart. If you want to really dive into the deep end on this stuff, I can recommend "Foundations of Mechanics" by Abraham and Marsden.

I don't know of many references on Bose-Einstein statistics. David Tong's lecture notes on statistical mechanics are good, though not very long.